# Bash string removal leading zeroes doesn't work in script

Tags: linux, string, bash

I obtain a different behavior when I call Bash string removal inside a script rather than directly in shell.

My case, running that directly in console:

```
id="00902"
echo ${id##+(0)}
```

output:

```
902
```

But, running this script, in a file

```
#!/bin/bash
id="00902"
echo ${id##+(0)}
```

Output:

```
00902
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have `+(0)` expansion you need `extglob` option to be set. By default it is set in an interactive shell, but is not set in scripts. You can check if it is set with `shopt` command.

The following should work

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
id="00902"
echo ${id##+(0)}
```